# Xamarin.forms Exception while loading assemblies 'Accessbility;

Tags: android, exception, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

When I try to run the app on an android phone I got several exceptions all with the same message:

> "Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? ..."

Most of these exceptions I was able to solve by copying the .dll file into my Droid project. I've been looking all over the internet, but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem. So I am asking it here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific line of code you're getting this Exception on?

Comment: No, usually it was just a file missing so I added that to my project. But this time it just says 'Accessibility. Don't know what that means.